# Quartz2D drawing without using drawRect:(CGRect)rect method

Tags: ios, quartz-graphics

In Quartz2D, can I draw any shapes without using `drawRect:(CGRect)rect` method?

Comment: what's up with the anonymous downvotes? +1 to offset anonymous downvoting. i see nothing wrong with this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. If you want to draw to a bitmap (as one example) and produce a CGImage, you could certainly create a CGBitmapContext, then use CoreGraphics as usual using that as your context.

If you want to draw to the display, do your work from within `drawRect:`, using the supplied graphics context.